# How do you remove a reference to a library from a ClickOnce install, when that library is no longer used?

Tags: clickonce

We're in the process of making various Windows applications, all of which are installed using ClickOnce. One of my colleagues included the assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Types into the applications, even though none of them use that library. It's been the bane of my existance ever since, because ClickOnce cannot install that assembly, as it needs to be installed into the GAC, which ClickOnce cannot do.

I've removed it from the project, and have rebuilt the solution, making a new ClickOnce deployment. I had thought that would be enough, but I'm wrong. New installations always fail saying that ClickOnce cannot install Microsoft.SqlServer.Types into the GAC. So, ClickOnce apparently wants to install everything that has ever been a part of the project, going back to the first ClickOnce installation for a project.

If I have corrected identified the problem, then how do I get rid of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types from where it is, in the chain of ClickOnce deployments for any program?

Answer (score 1):

I am wrong about there being some sort of remnant of the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.DLL` in the ClickOnce deployment. I discovered that `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` was still in the project's Properties | Publish | Application Files area. I excluded it from there, then built it and republished it. The users were able to install it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.